# PHP string replace with html button

Tags: php, str-replace

is it possible to str_replace or some form of other method which allows you to replace text within some content with a html button?

I have this tag @create@ within a paragraph that I would like to replace with `<a href="link here">Create Account</a>`

is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think that's any different from any other use of `str_replace()`?

Comment: @Barmar because I was using html tags to replace it with but yeah realised the actual source of the textarea value is just a string anyway so yeah my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use **[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**.

Here's a quick sample:

```
$variable = 'Hello, create your account: @create@';
echo str_replace("@create@", "<a href=\"link here\">Create Account</a>", $variable);
```

The example above will output:

```
Hello, create your account: <a href="link here">Create Account</a>
```

Comment: Thank's for that, for some reason I was having issues trying to use str_replace with html tags so i assumed it wouldnt work for them ( I was wrong).